# Как скрыть (убрать) <span> если переменная не пустая?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть код PHP

```
foreach ($manga as $rowGlava) {
    $glavs .= '<li>
        <a class="item-serial fx-row fx-between fx-middle" href="'.$full_read.'?t='.$rowGlava["tom"].'&g='.$rowGlava["glava"].'&p=1">
            <div class="item-title">Том '.$rowGlava["tom"].'. Глава '.$rowGlava["glava"].'<span class="testing"> - </span><span>'.$rowGlava["title"].' </span></div>  
            <div class="is-serie">Читать</div>
        </a>
    </li>';
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если $rowGlava["glava"] не имеет значение, span.testing скрывался?

Comment: добавьте условие в начале, если значение не пустое, пишите в переменную строку со спаном, если пустая - пустую строку. Потом в $glavs вписываете созданную ранее переменную в том месте где должен быть спан. Можно также использовать тернарные операторы - https://php720.com/lesson/19

Comment: не понимаю людей, не использующих шаблонизаторы

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте таким образом реализовать:

```
foreach ($manga as $rowGlava) {
    $glavs .= '<li>
        <a class="item-serial fx-row fx-between fx-middle" href="'.$full_read.'?t='.$rowGlava["tom"].'&g='.$rowGlava["glava"].'&p=1">
            <div class="item-title">Том '.$rowGlava["tom"].'. Глава '.$rowGlava["glava"].(isset($rowGlava["glava"])?'<span class="testing"> - </span>':'').'<span>'.$rowGlava["title"].' </span></div>  
            <div class="is-serie">Читать</div>
        </a>
    </li>';
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]